# Canon 70D Viewfinder info battery logo dead pixel?

Tags: canon, dslr, troubleshooting, repair, viewfinder

It's not a problem to me, but I was just wondering is it meant to be there or is it manufacturing error?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was just wondering is it meant to be there or is it manufacturing error?

It's definitely intentional -- it's the same in the viewfinder and on the top LCD on my Canon 6D. However, the icon on the Battery Info page on the main screen lacks the open spot.

My educated guess is that the hole in the battery icon provides access for the conductors that control the internal segments of the icon. With both LED and LCD displays, the visual elements and the teensy little wires the control them are likely all printed on the substrate in the same plane. Without the hole, those wires would have to cross the outline, requiring two layers instead of one, and that'd add significant complexity and expense.

So it's definitely not a manufacturing error, but probably just a manufacturing constraint that the designers had to deal with.

Answer (score 10):

That's how it's meant to look.

Refer the [manual from Canon's website](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300012004/04/EOS_70D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf), page 23:

[image: Canon 70D viewfinder, p23 of manual]

Refer also p36: the top LCD should be the same.